# Keyboard Shortcut to select flutter widget in vs code

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

Is there any shortcut in vs code to select all the code inside a highlighted `Flutter Widget` ??

and what  is it ??

because it is getting a bit messy with long code to detect the end of the widget

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is a shortcut. But if your problem only is to find the end of a widget I think I might have a solution for you.
I would suggest you to use the dart code formatting. After that, your code should not only be perfectly formatted but there should also be automatically created comments at the end of the widget (e.g. // Text).
You can format your code by right clicking on it and selecting the "format code". In addition you can set Visual Studio to format your code every time you hot reload it. I found this to be immensely helpful.
I really hope I could help you with the problem.